# How to diasplay stock quantity of goods in node-product.tpl.php

Tags: ubercart

I need to get quantity of goods in stock and display a number in the product page node-product.tpl.php.

Here is what I added in the template, but `uc_stock_level()` seems not to work properly.

```
$stock = uc_stock_level($node->model);   
if ($stock > 0) {
    print $stock;
} else {
    print $stock;
}
```

I am using Ubercart 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much to [`uc_stock_level()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_stock%21uc_stock.module/function/uc_stock_level/7). Check that you are supplying a model/SKU that is in the table and it is active. If that's the case, you might need to flush your cache to pick up new changes in your template file.